# Disable Mint Cinnamon Keyboard Shortcut, Shift + Numpad != Numlock

Tags: linux-mint, cinnamon, numpad, shift, numlock

I have just started using Linux Mint with Cinnamon Desktop Environment, but I have come accross an annoying feature that I can't find out how to remove. When the `num lock` is off, the right `numpad` acts as direction keys, but when I press `shift` with the `numpad`, it acts like a numpad, unless the `num lock` is off, then it is the opposite. I was wondering how to disable the `shift +` inverting the functionality

Answer (score 2):

You should probably change the setting

> Control Center -> Keyboard -> Layouts -> Options -> Miscellaneous
>   Compatibility Options -> Shift with Numeric Keypads works as in MS
>   Windows

Note that this feature has some limitations. For example, I'm used to clipboard operation Ctrl-Insert/Shift-Insert using insert on the numpad. But the known [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xkeyboard-config/+bug/32768) prevents from using them.

Comment: This only addresses the issue when numlock is on, it works under that condition, but then HOME and END don't work, you have to turn numlock off for HOME and END to work. How can this be addressed with numlock OFF?

Answer (score 2):

Based on the Ask Ubuntu post
[XUbuntu: Make Shift+NumPad work like Windows](https://askubuntu.com/questions/57079/xubuntu-make-shiftnumpad-work-like-windows),
and especially
[this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/500941/963426)
and its comments, making Linux Mint 18 (Cinnamon) make the NumPad work like in Windows
is in:

*System Settings > Hardware > Keyboard > Layouts > Miscellaneous compatibility options*

Expand the option and check
"Numlock on: digits, Shift switches to arrow keys, Numlock off: always arrow keys (as in MS Windows)".

For other Linux distributions, some more advice can be found in the above
linked post and in the article
[Fixing wrong Shift+Numpad (keypad) behaviour in Emacs](http://www.linux-pages.com/2013/06/fix-wrongshift-numpad-keypad-behaviour-in-emacs/)

Answer (score 1):

Just in case someone needs the solution for Mint Olivia:

In the menu, search for 'Region & Language', and then you can go to the solution that was suggested by Maksee:
Layouts -> Options -> Miscellaneous Compatibility Options -> Shift with Numeric Keypads works as in MS Windows

Good luck!

Comment: Same as the the other answer, this only addresses when numlock is ON, the question is how to address this when numlock is OFF.